# Modular Arithmetic Inverse Exponent Simplification

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Need help on where to start here.

Given $a^b\mod c = d$, where $b$, $c$ and $d$ is known, how do I find $a$?

Thank!

---

I just wrote some arbitrary number here:

$x^{13} \mod 47 = 17$, how do I convert this to x = .... mod 47? From my understanding, it will be $x= 7^{1/13} \mod 47$ but how do I simplify that to an all-integer form.

Comment: Do we have any constraints on the values of $b,c,$ and $d$?

Comment: We have a constraints on the number of digit available on the calculator used to perform the computation to find a. @mapierce271

Answer (score 1):

You do the same thing as if this was an equation in more familiar arithmetic: compute the $b$-th roots of $d$ modulo $c$.

Comment: Ah okay, can do that with a calculator. Although it mention about the digit limitation of the calculator used. Do you know anything about that? @Hurkyl

Comment: I'm used to having a computer program that can either deal with big integers, or actually has modular exponentiation built-in. If you have to do it yourself, you could use one of the "square and multiply" algorithms for computing exponentiation.

Comment: I chose an arbitrary number here $x^{13} \mod 47 = 17$, how do I convert this to x = .... mod 47? Because in this case it will be $x= 7^{1/13} \mod 47$ how do I simplify that? @Hurkyl

Comment: What confuse me here is the exponent $1/13$, what can we do with it to simplify the expression? Cause if there is a rule for it, please do tell.

Comment: @Stud: I had assumed the phrase "modular roots" would ring a bell, or at least provide a hint for searching. Your particular example is a simple case, though, since in arithmetic modulo 47, exponents are integers modulo 46 (or modulo a factor of 46, depending on the particular base), and you can simplify 1/13 modulo 46.

Comment: it didn't ring a bell but i would look through it. Thank you! @Hurkyl